# Why are there so many clock sources and oscillator designs in one system?

Tags: oscillator, frequency, clock, crystal

[image]

Lately I've been studying the old Nintendo NES diagrams (made in the 1980's) and came across two oscillators in the system from which they also tap different points of the circuit to source clock signal for different devices.

Left oscillator is for the CPU, PPU (like the graphics processor), and other stuff. Right oscillator is for the CIC (anti-piracy protection circuit, which is a 4bit MCU).

I understand you may need different frequencies for a variety of reasons. But..

- Why do they have to get the signal from many parts of the oscillator
  circuit?, I mean, you could just have one clock signal and route that
  to all the IC's across the system.
- Why did they use two different designs?, you could use the same
  design and just change the crystal.
- Why didn't they just use a frequency divider?, you could just use one
  oscillator circuit and get the frequencies you need from there.
- Also, why is there a variable capacitor? tuning reasons?

Comment: Generating composite video requires very specific frequencies that you can't easily divide or multiply to get unless you are already an integer multiple if it, ala X1 frequency. The CIC may simply be on its own clock because its meant to shut everything else down. More difficult to circumvent and get the system working if everything is shut down.

Comment: Where did you get these diagrams from?

Comment: @BruceAbbott openTendo

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple questions here, but I'll try to address them one at a time.  But first, realize that you reviewing an old design with a modern mindset; a lot of the options we have today may not have been available (or economical) when that particular circuit was designed.

So, to Q1,

> Why do they have to get the signal from many parts of the oscillator
> circuit?

- most likely because of loading and specific capacitance requirements.  Note that the PPU, System and Cpu clocks may come from the same source, but use different topologies and different capacitances - that probably reflects the requirements of each consumer of the 'same' frequency.  On the other side, the clock goes through buffers to ensure there is no loading and still utilizes different capacitors.

Q2:

> Why did they use two different designs?, you could use the same design
> and just change the crystal

.
Probably because of different requirements.  Different consumers of clocks generated by crystals have different requirements; that is no different today, if you look at most PIC microcontrollers, and even the 32bit parts, they all have small peculiarities on loading and capacitance for their clock.

Q3:

> Why didn't they just use a frequency divider?, you could just use one
> oscillator circuit and get the frequencies you need from there.

I only see a 4 MHz and 21.47MHz frequency - not sure you could get one from the other.

Q4:

> Also, why is there a variable capacitor? tuning reasons?

Yes.